# where to get detailed information about some file format?

Tags: data-structures, databases, filesystems

i want to learn about the structure of a .blk file but the problem is I don't know where to look for detailed information of this sort, most of the google searches I made gave me links to viewers.

Comment: This question is off-topic for this site as it really isn't about computer science (principles) but IT (practice). What I'd do if I were you is search for open source software written to read such files, try it, and if it works, look at the code. If you run into issues with that, try Stack Overflow or Super User.

Comment: (There is [file-extension.org](https://www.file-extension.org/extensions/blk).)